# Android studio :Error:(396, 29) String types not allowed (at 'bg.jpg' with value 'bg')

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]  (this is the .jpg image I am trying to insert)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout     
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg"
tools:context="com.awani.simpleapp.mainactivity"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="89dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">
```

this is the code statement from drawable file:

```
<drawable name="bg.jpg">bg</drawable>
```

How to fix this error?Please help.Is there any issue related to sdk version?(I am absolute beginner in android)

Comment: try to change name of your image in drawable....
and please can you share that image ?

Comment: well your code looks fine it must be something to do with image, try a clean project and rebuild project and then it may work